# Configuration Error in Cassandra Kerberos Authentication with Java

Tags: cassandra, kerberos, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to connect to Cassandra cluster through Kerberos ticket cache with following set of configs -

```
java -Dcassaandra.ip.address=<IPaddress> \
  -Djava.security.auth.login.config=kerb-client.conf \
  -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true \
  -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false \
  -Djava.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf -jar test-kerberos.jar
```

**kerb-client.conf**:
CassandraJavaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useTicketCache=true ticketCache=cacheFile principal="abc@abc.net";
};

I am getting following error -

```
Unexpected error during transport initialization (java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
        Line 3: expected [option value])
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$2.apply(Connection.java:205)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$2.apply(Connection.java:191)
```

It seems like that there is some config missing but i am unable to identify the root cause.
Please advise on the corrective steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java driver needs to have a custom authenticator configured in order to authenticate using Kerberos.

Instaclustr has an open-source [Kerberos authenticator for Cassandra](https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/kerberos-authenticator-for-apache-cassandra/) that works with the Java driver. Details and code are available here:

- [Cassandra Kerberos authenticator](https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-kerberos)
- [Java driver Kerberos plugin](https://github.com/instaclustr/cassandra-java-driver-kerberos)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already using com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.5.1. Below is my sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I am already using com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.5.1. Below is my sample code snippet.

```
 Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(ipAddress)
                .withAuthProvider(KerberosAuthProvider.builder().withSaslProperties(saslProperties).build())
                .withSSL()
                .build();
cluster.connect();
```

**The issue got fixed after changing the ticketCache file name. It seems like that i was referring to incorrect cache file**.Now, i seem to be getting something else - No valid credentials exception provided.
But i have moved ahead from basic configuration error.